# Variable not created when restore graph with import_meta_graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to restore graph from model which I train with [TensorFlow tutorials](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py), then I try to restore the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import reader
from ptb_word_lm import PTBInput, PTBModel, get_config, run_epoch

def main(_):
    checkpoint_path = "/Users/roger/data/ptb_out"
    checkpoint_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path)

    raw_data = reader.ptb_raw_data("/Users/roger/data/simple-examples/small_data")
    train_data, valid_data, test_data, _ = raw_data

    config = get_config()
    eval_config = get_config()
    eval_config.batch_size = 1
    eval_config.num_steps = 1


    with tf.Session() as session:
        initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-config.init_scale,
                                                config.init_scale)

        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint_path + ".meta")
        saver.restore(session, checkpoint_path)

        with tf.name_scope("Test"):
            test_input = PTBInput(config=eval_config, data=test_data, name="TestInput")
            with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=True, initializer=initializer):
                mtest = PTBModel(is_training=False, config=eval_config,
                                input_=test_input)
            test_perplexity = run_epoch(session, mtest)
            print("Test Perplexity: %.3f" % test_perplexity)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

However, I find that Varible `Model/embedding` which created [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L136) is not restored from graph. So I get error like this:

```
 ValueError: Variable Model/embedding does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

So how can I restore the model correctly?

Comment: I think since your `Model` scope is nested inside `Test`, the embeddings become `Model/Test/embedding` that confuses TF

Comment: @gokul_uf but according to the training code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L359), it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I think, since you set reuse=True in your variable scope, it tries to find that variable instead of creating it when you call PTBModel(). If you use get_variable() with reuse=True in a scope, it will never create a variable.